# Representing Membership Levels Django Models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model, affiliate

So I have a model in Django that represents affiliates. The user receives a commission for each referral they get. How much the referrer receives depends on their user level. The user level depends on how many referrals they have. Under 5 referrals = Basic, under 10 referrals = Intermediate, under 15 referrals = Advanced.

How can I code the model so the user level is automatically determined by the amount of referrals an affiliate has? Lets say

```
class Affiliate(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User)
    affiliate_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    referral_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    user_level = (
('B', 'Basic'),
('I', 'Intermediate'),
('A', 'Advanced'),
 default='B')
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(referral_id, default=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

A django Model (or the database underlying it) is static data. To make run-time decisions is what Model methods are for:

```
class Affiliate(model.Model):
    affiliate_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    …

    def user_level(self):
        levels = [(5, 'B'), …]
        for referrals, category in levels:
             if self.some_field < referrals:
                 return category
```

The nice thing about Model methods is that they behave like Model fields in the rest of the framework. It isn't clear that your Affiliate model has a referral count available to it, so I used `some_field` in its place. Depending on how data-driven you want this lookup to be, it might warrant its own Model.

The [django tutorial covers Model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) in its first section, which makes me believe that questions about them have been quite common.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted some reassurance to be honest. I was considering using a model method, but I wanted someone more experienced to give me the go ahead.